# Reading data from ShapeFile

Tags: java, swing, gis, shapefile, geotools

i am new to GIS field and i am using [geotools](http://geotools.org) to read/view shape files how so how can i read data about certain point in shape file without using InfoTool , for now i am capable of reading and viewing shp file and i can use InfoTool , Zoom tool ,...etc

```
    private void openButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    JFileDataStoreChooser x = new JFileDataStoreChooser("shp");
    x.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    x.setFileSelectionMode(JFileDataStoreChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    int val = x.showOpenDialog(null);
    if ((val == JFileDataStoreChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) || (val == JFileDataStoreChooser.ERROR_OPTION)) {
        return;
    }

    File file = x.getSelectedFile();
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
        MapContent map = null;

        if (mapPane.getMapContent() == null) {
            map = new MapContent();
            map.setTitle("Quickstart");
        } else {
            map = mapPane.getMapContent();
        }

        Style style;
        style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
        FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);

        map.addLayer(layer);
        mapPane.setMapContent(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
    }
```

and what i want to do is :

```
mapPane.addMouseListener(new MapMouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
               // ev.getWorldPos();
               // get data from shape file if found about position
               // view this data 
               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(data);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you clarify exactly what you want to do? how is this different to the info tool?

Comment: I want to take that data and output it into joptionpane or taple or any output else

Comment: @iant can you tell me how ???!!

Comment: have you looked at info tool?

Comment: I don't know where to look ??!